# When the last version of Java Media Framework was released?

Tags: java, jmf

When it was released the latest version of JMF? Is it useful to study about the JMF? Please suggest me.. But there is very small amount of source only there? Why? Suggest me..

Comment: After 2004, there is no updates and no sources for JMF.. What's the reason? Is there any concepts introduced instead of JMF?

Answer (score 4):

The last version was released [2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework), there has been an addon in 2004 as far as I know (MP3 support). But then, there haven't been changes anymore. Eventually JMF will be superseded by the [JMC](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#jmc) (Java Media Components), which is currently in development for JavaFX, but has less features right now than the JMF (i.e. streaming is missing). There are open source works that enrich the current JMF ([1](http://fmj-sf.net/),[2](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/)) or provide an own API ([3](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/)).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework) version 2.1.1e was released almost 7 years ago, May 23, 2003.

Comment: Fine.. But after that (2004), there is no updates and no sources for JMF.. What's the reason? Is there any concepts introduced instead of JMF?

Comment: There are several [alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives) listed.  Apparently Sun isn't interested in developing this library or keeping it up-to-date.